# OS X client gets SSL certificate error when trying to join OD

Tags: macos, osx-server, ssl, open-directory

I switched from self signed to signing my own certificates using a CA I created on the server. OS X Server has a list of the certificates outlined in blue now for its hostname, Code Signing Certificate, and OD Intermediate CA. I have the CA I created copied to my client.

How can I resolve this SSL issue?

Comment: Is your server still using a .local hostname.  Did you change the OD to use the new cert?

Answer (score 1):

The OD server on 10.10 uses the identity certificate pointed to by the "MACHINE_IDENTITY" identity preference. Using Keychain Access or the security command line tool change the identity preference to point to your new CA signed cert.